# PHP: Selecting, grouping, and showing only arrays with the same key value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that holds log data from a vehicle's OBD-II reader. The application that interfaces with the reader collects a large amount (usually well over 2,000) of data point sets. Each of these data point sets gets its own row in the table, resulting in something like this:

```
+---------------+----------------------------------+---------------+----+----+-----+
| session       | id                               | time          | kd | kf | ... |
+---------------+----------------------------------+---------------+----+----+-----+
| 1420236074526 | 5cff4a3cc80b22cecb7de85266b25355 | 1420236074534 | 14 | 8  | ... |
| 1420236074526 | 5cff4a3cc80b22cecb7de85266b25355 | 1420236075476 | 17 | 8  | ... |
| 1420236074526 | 5cff4a3cc80b22cecb7de85266b25355 | 1420236075476 | 19 | 8  | ... |
| 1420236074526 | 5cff4a3cc80b22cecb7de85266b25355 | 1420236075476 | 23 | 8  | ... |
| 1420236074526 | 5cff4a3cc80b22cecb7de85266b25355 | 1420236077477 | 25 | 8  | ... |
+---------------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------+-----+
```

`k5` and `kf` are the vehicle data types (vehicle speed and ambient air temperature, respectively).

There are two indexes in this table (which is called `raw_logs`):

- **session** maps to columns `session` and `id`
- **id** maps to column `id`

What I'd like to do is grab all of the rows that have the same timestamp (*1420236074526*, for example),  and lump them together into a "session". The goal here is to create a select list where I can view data by session. Ideally, I'd have something like this as the output:

```
<select>
  <option>January 1, 2015 - 7:43AM</option>
  <option>January 1, 2015 - 5:15PM</option>
  <option>January 2, 2015, - 7:38AM</option>
  ...
</select>
```

---

This is what I have so far (I'm using [Medoo](http://medoo.in/) to try and simplify the queries):

```
$session = $database->query("SELECT * FROM raw_logs USE INDEX (session)");

$sessionArray = array();
foreach($session as $session){
  $s_time = $session["session"];
  $sessionArray[$s_time] = array(
    "vehicle_speed" => $session["kd"],
    "ambient_air_temp" => $session["kf"]
  );
} print_r($sessionArray);
```

This works... sort of. I get the session time as the array and `kd` and `kf` under that with the correct key/value pairs, but it doesn't seem to want to iterate through the whole thing. There are around 25,000 rows in the table at the moment, but it's only returning a few, and there doesn't seem to be any logical order to the listing... it'll return two results from January 8th, one from the 9th, 4 from the 10th, etc.

---

**What would be the best way to select all sessions with the same time stamp, group them, and create a selectable object that will only display the data for the given session?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not ordering the query, there likely won't be any logical order to the listing. Also, you are overwriting the session data where duplicate values exist in the `session` column. You likely want to do something like `$sessionArray[$s_time][] = array(...` to append each row under the session id. Also, if you are having trouble, it is best to limit the results from your query down to like 20-100 and keep massaging until you get the result you want.